# SQL Server query problem

Tags: sql-server

Table User

```
    Id Username
    1   A
    2   B
    3   C
    4   D
```

Table Roles

```
Id UserId Role      Status      Expiration 
1  1      Admin        Active       01-01-2011 
2  2      Client      Active       02-02-2011 
3  3      Applicant    Active      03-03-2011 
4  4      Client       Inactive     04-04-2011
```

Output:

```
A              B          C                D       -- this is the username  
Admin        Client      Applicant       Client     -- role of the username
Active      Active      Active          inactive   -- status of the username
01-01-2011  02-02-2011  03-03-2011      04-04-2011 -- expiration of username
```

I want to achieved the result above. **User and Roles** table are having a one to one relationship.

**Username** along with the roles information should be in one column respectively. 
For example **User A** having a roles information of **Admin, Active and 01-01-2011** came from **Role, Status, Expiration** fields respectively of table **Roles**.

Any help pls on how to achieved this result?

Comment: If this is for a report, or something similar, you'd do better to do this kind of formatting in your reporting tool rather than in SQL. In SQL, the values in each column are always meant to be of the same type - but your columns have text and dates being intermingled.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use both [UNPIVOT and PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx). UNPIVOT can convert columns Role, Status and Expiration to rows. And PIVOT can convert Username rows to columns.

```
WITH Roles (Id, UserId, Role, Status, Expiration) AS
(
    SELECT 1, 1, 'Admin', 'Active', '01-01-2011'
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 2, 'Client', 'Active', '02-02-2011 '
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 3, 'Applicant', 'Active', '03-03-2011' 
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 , 4, 'Client', 'Inactive', '04-04-2011' 
),
[User] (Id, Username) AS
(
    SELECT 1, 'A'
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'B'
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'C'
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'D'
)
SELECT Fields.FieldId,
    Pivoted.*
FROM
(
    SELECT [User].UserName,
        CAST(Roles.Role AS nvarchar(100)) Role,
        CAST(Roles.Status AS nvarchar(100)) Status,
        CAST(Roles.Expiration AS nvarchar(100)) Expiration
    FROM Roles
    JOIN [User] ON [User].Id = Roles.UserId
) RawData
UNPIVOT (FieldValue FOR FieldName
         IN ([Role], [Status], [Expiration])) Unpivoted
PIVOT (MIN(FieldValue) FOR UserName IN ([A], [B], [C], [D])) Pivoted
JOIN 
(
    SELECT 1, 'Role'
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Status'
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Expiration'
) Fields (FieldId, FieldName) 
    ON Fields.FieldName = Pivoted.FieldName
ORDER BY Fields.FieldId
```

Output:

```
FieldId  FieldName   A           B           C           D
1        Role        Admin       Client      Applicant   Client
2        Status      Active      Active      Active      Inactive
3        Expiration  01-01-2011  02-02-2011  03-03-2011  04-04-2011
```

Comment: how to set up dynamically the statement below SELECT 1, 1, 'Admin', 'Active', '01-01-2011'
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 2, 'Client', 'Active', '02-02-2011 '
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 3, 'Applicant', 'Active', '03-03-2011' 
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 , 4, 'Client', 'Inactive', '04-04-2011'

Comment: Just remove all code between "WITH" and "[User] (Id, Username)"

Answer (score 0):

First setup the example data in a sql script

```
Declare  @User table (ID int, Username varchar(50))
Insert Into @User (id, username) values (1,'A')
Insert Into @User (id, username) values (2,'B')
Insert Into @User (id, username) values (3,'C')
Insert Into @User (id, username) values (4,'D')
Declare  @role table (ID int, UserID int, Role varchar(50), Status varchar(50), Expiration DateTime)
Insert Into @role (id, UserID, Role, Status, Expiration) values (1, 1, 'Admin', 'Active', '01-01-2011' )
Insert Into @role (id, UserID, Role, Status, Expiration) values (2, 2, 'Client',      'Active',  '02-02-2011' )
Insert Into @role (id, UserID, Role, Status, Expiration) values (3, 3, 'Applicant',    'Active',  '03-03-2011' )
Insert Into @role (id, UserID, Role, Status, Expiration) values (4, 4, 'Client',   'Inactive',    '04-04-2011' )
```

Then below put the following and run the lot, you'll see why it's not a very nice way to use Pivot.

```
SELECT 
[A], [B], [C], [D]
FROM
(Select Username, Role, Status, Expiration 
FROM @User u
Inner Join @role r
On u.ID = r.UserID) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
Max(Role)
FOR Username IN ([A], [B], [C], [D])
) AS PivotTable1;
```

Output

```
Admin   NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    Client  NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    Applicant   NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    Client
```

Essentiatilly you will need to combine multiple pivots to get the effect you want, and it groups all users into a single row, so it doesn't make a very simple result set.

have you considered using For XML?

```
Select Username, Role, Status, Expiration 
FROM @User u
Inner Join @role r
On u.ID = r.UserID
For XML Auto
```

output...

```
<u Username="A">
  <r Role="Admin" Status="Active" Expiration="2011-01-01T00:00:00" />
</u>
<u Username="B">
  <r Role="Client" Status="Active" Expiration="2011-02-02T00:00:00" />
</u>
<u Username="C">
  <r Role="Applicant" Status="Active" Expiration="2011-03-03T00:00:00" />
</u>
<u Username="D">
  <r Role="Client" Status="Inactive" Expiration="2011-04-04T00:00:00" />
</u>
```